# 3D Barplot visualization on leaflet map in R

Tags: r, 3d, leaflet, gis, bar-chart

I am using R and Leaflet (in a shiny app).
I have point data which I want to visualize through a 3D plot on a map - like this: https://slipiste.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/3d-bar-plot-on-a-map-in-r/
Understandable how to do that if not done on leaflet. But how to do plot that on a leaflet map? Is there a way to do that?

They way I see it would have to overlay a shapefile (transparent) over my leaflet map and plot the 3D Barplot on that shapefile. However, that seems like a messy workaround. But, I did not find any websites on that topic. Any hints?

Comment: @TheTime yep. That one needs to be interactive. Thats the tricky part I guess. I need the functionality of leaflet (panning, zooming, its .js functions) and the 3D Barplot on. Overlaying with a shapefile was my first guess, but I thought there might be a more elegant way :)

Comment: @TheTime na. No ArcGIS! R and leaflet it is! I also wonder how that would work with the perspective. Leaflet is sort of "straight from top down", nothing like the example I posted. 3D Barcharts would look "straight from top down" like simple squares.

Comment: what about a raster image https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html

Comment: @MLavoie How would that help?

Comment: I wonder if you could create your 3D Barplot in Google Earth, export as a raster and then add to your leaflet map. Anyway, I don't think I ever see 3D shapes on leaflet...good luck!

Comment: @MLavoie Hm, Then I would rather go for the shape version. I  am workin a shiny App, so whatever the data is, is changing, since the user defines the input.

Comment: Might D3 be of interest to you? I know you can overlay D3 on top of leaflet pretty easily and here is an example of bar plots in D3: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/4531633 . This was taken from the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301724/how-to-draw-a-3d-bar-chart-on-a-world-map-with-d3-js

Answer (score 1):

A few years on `library(mapdeck)` lets you plot a 3D bars on a map

```
library(mapdeck)

set_token("MAPBOX_TOKEN") ## you'll need an API token

df <- read.csv(paste0(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/deck.gl-data/master/',
  'examples/3d-heatmap/heatmap-data.csv'
))

mapdeck(
  style = mapdeck_style('dark')
  , pitch = 45 
  ) %>%
  add_grid(
    data = df[1:30000, ]
    , lat = "lat"
    , lon = "lng"
    , cell_size = 1000
    , elevation_scale = 50
    , layer_id = "grid_layer"
  )
```

[image]

And from v0.2.1006 you can use the `add_column()` function